# How to fetch Data on load component using React-Redux and Axios?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I have a need to fetch data from an API on component load, am using axios to fetch data, I need to save the response to the state and get back when the component load.
But i could do as am new to this.

My codes as below.

**Sales.js** : (This is where I fetch My components)

```
function SalesDesk() {
    return (
        <div>
             <FoodScreen />
        </div>
    )}
export default SalesDesk;
```

**FoodScreen.js** (This is where i need to list my results to a variable, to map it later)

```
function FoodScreen() {
    return(
        <div className="sdFoodScreenMain">
        {console.log(items)} // The results should be displayed here
        </div>
    )}
export default FoodScreen;
```

**API.js** (Here is where where i use my axios Router)

```
const API_URL = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/`; //Mock api for test purposes

export const GetAllItems = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
      axios.get(API_URL)
          .then(response => {
              dispatch(allItemsList(response.data));
          })
  }
};
```

**ItemsReducer.js** (The reducer Logic)

```
const ItemsReducer =(state:Array  = null, action) =>{
    if (action.type === 'ALL_ITEMS') {
        return GetAllItems ;
    } else {
        return state= null;
    }
};
export default ItemsReducer
```

**SalesAction.js** (Action list)

```
export const allItemsList = () => {
    return {
        type: 'ALL_ITEMS'
    };
};
```

All I need to do is fetch the the data from the API and display it in the console, when the component renders.so that I can display it in a map of div boxes for future purposes. Am new to both react and Redux, so ignore if any logic or implementation issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to add an useDispatch on the component render, so it could fetch the data to the component on load.

```
import Reactfrom 'react'
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {GetAllItems} from 'API' //File containing the axios function

export function SalesDesk() {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(GetAllItems())
    return (
        <div>
             <FoodScreen />
        </div>
    )}
```

This helped me to fetch add add to state on component load.

Answer (score 0):

At first Router.js is a bad name(api.js etc), You should connect Sales.js to redux, using { connect } from 'react-redux'. See there https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react and call action to fetch data in Sales.js